# VTP domain name configuration

Tags: vtp

I believe only way to configure VTP domain is by CLI.,
Anyway i heard when we configure trunk from a switch A(which is in VTP domain (say cisco))
to another switch B which dont belong to any VTP domain., the second switch automatically assigned to switch A (VTP domain)., is that so ? i cant find anywhere this.,

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is correct!

When Cisco implemented VTP, they left a "null" value for exactly this reason. If a VTP client or server with a null domain receives a VTP message with the domain populated, it will assume the domain of the received message and add applicable VLANs to its database.

You can find more information here:

[Catalyst 6500 Series Switch Cisco IOS Software Configuration Guide - Configuring VTP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SXF/native/configuration/guide/swcg/vtp.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Its true. The 2nd switch will be assigned the domain from 1st switch.

A quick test to prove it.

Quick output: running-configs do not have the vtp configurations.

```
!
Switch#show run
Building configuration...
.
.
.
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
.
.
.
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
end


Switch#show vtp status
VTP Version                     : 2
Configuration Revision          : 0
Maximum VLANs supported locally : 255
Number of existing VLANs        : 5
VTP Operating Mode              : Server
***VTP Domain Name                 : HK***
VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled
VTP V2 Mode                     : Disabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
MD5 digest                      : 0xC2 0x79 0x35 0xAE 0x48 0x96 0xB9 0xE0 
Configuration last modified by 0.0.0.0 at 0-0-00 00:00:00
Local updater ID is 0.0.0.0 (no valid interface found)
Switch#
```